# Size and position of icons not save in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, icons

When I move or resize icons and then refresh the explorer, icons size and position reset to default. can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

***Try*** changing it from here:

[image]

That *should* save as I just tested it on Windows 10.

Comment: thanks for your answer. at beginning of installing windows its was working. but after a while no. Now if I changed the icon sizes after restart those come back to default. I think the registry has changed.